# Variable not initializing - Unable to return a value

Tags: java, class

In the below; I am attempting to print some information that the user has input. I believe I have a scope issue. When the user selects A; they are able to make a new character and then it prints their name. If they then press V; it fails with an exception.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable newChar might not have been initialized

If they have added a new character; why would the program not allow me to print getFirstName in choice V but it DOES do so in choice A?

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rpgmanager;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Aaron
 */
public class RpgManager {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set Run Boolean to true
        boolean running = true;
        // "Splash Screen here"
        System.out.println("Welcome to character generator.");
        // If the program is running; offer the user options
        while(running) {
                System.out.println("A: New Char ; V: View ; S: Save ; D: Delete ; Q: Quit");
                // Initialize the scanner
                Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
                // Prepare to accept a string
                String decision;
                // Get the user input
                decision = user_input.next();
                // We switch the input to lowecase here and compare
                switch (decision.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "a": 
                        Character newChar = new Character();
                        System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName());
                            break;
                    case "s":
                            break;
                    case "d": 
                            break;
                    case "v":
                        try {
                            System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName());    
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("You have an exception - ");
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                            break;
                    case "q": System.exit(0); // Kill the program
                                break;
                    default: System.out.println("You did not select a viable option.");
                             System.out.println("Try again.");
                                break;
                }
        }
    }
}


/*
 * 
 * 
 */
package rpgmanager;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Aaron
 */
public class Character {
        private String First_Name;
        private String Last_Name;
        private String Height;
        private int Weight;
        private int Age;

        public Character() {
            System.out.println("Creating new character...");
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is your first name?");
            First_Name = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("What is your last name?");
            Last_Name = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("What is your height?");
            Height = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("What is your weight?");
            Weight = user_input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What is your age?");
            Age = user_input.nextInt();
        }

     /**
     *
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return First_Name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return Last_Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `case "v":`, you won't even have `newChar` because `newChar` is defined in `case "a":` and you can't have both of them run with your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the variable newChar is initialized here:

```
case "a": 
    Character newChar = new Character(); //Here
    System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName());
    break; //"break" makes
```

But that block of code is only going to be executed when you choose "a". When you choose "v", then the following code is executed:

```
System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName()); //The variable newChar is not initialized
```

I believe you are looking for the following:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set Run Boolean to true
    boolean running = true;
    // "Splash Screen here"
    System.out.println("Welcome to character generator.");
    // If the program is running; offer the user options
    while(running) {
            System.out.println("A: New Char ; V: View ; S: Save ; D: Delete ; Q: Quit");
            // Initialize the scanner
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Prepare to accept a string
            String decision;
            // Get the user input
            decision = user_input.next();
            // We switch the input to lowecase here and compare
            Character newChar = new Character(); //Now the variable will always be initialized
            switch (decision.toLowerCase()) {
                case "a":                         
                    System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "s":
                    break;
                case "d": 
                    break;
                case "v":
                    try {
                        System.out.println(newChar.getFirstName());    
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("You have an exception - ");
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                        break;
                case "q": System.exit(0); // Kill the program
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("You did not select a viable option.");
                    System.out.println("Try again.");
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.It made it extremely easy to see what I needed to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign something to the `newChar` variable before the `switch` statement. The most logical solution here would be to add a

```
Character newChar = null;
```

line outside the `switch` statement, and then check in the `q` case if `newChar` is `null`, and print some kind of `No Character has been created yet` message in that case.

Comment: But then I would not be able to control WHEN they build the character... Or would there be a way to allow them to only initialize new Character() on selection to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Its the scope problem
you have declared newChar in choice A but not in choice v

case "a": 
                        Character newChar = new Character();

so declare newChar in while or choice v